# slide popup when keyboard appears wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox, popup

I have a user-control with lot of text boxes which I add as a child in a popup which appears on click of a button.

problem is when I click on second last or third last textbox the virtual keyboard overlaps the popup. I'm unable to see the text which I input

what can be done to slide the popup in this case

```
        Popup popMisc = new Popup();
        popMisc.VerticalOffset = 80;
        popMisc.HorizontalOffset = 10;


        ucMisc objMisc = new ucMisc();
        popMisc.Child = objMisc;
        popMisc.IsOpen = true;
        base.IsHitTestVisible = false;

        objMisc.btnContinue.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                popMisc.IsOpen = false;
                base.IsHitTestVisible = true;
            };
```

Comment: Just navigate to a new Page (with textboxes) instead if showing Popup.

Comment: I any one don't know the ans, don't downvote. pity on them